# Catch click event on any element inside a div

Tags: jquery, onclick

I have a `div` that contains a bunch of elements. This `div` will be hidden (animated `fadeOut()`) if the screen size is smaller than 767px. But if the user clicks on any of the element inside this `div`, I want to stop the `fadeOut()`.

But as how I see it right now, I'll have to add a click event for each element I have inside this `div`. Isn't there a more elegant way to catch all click events inside a `div`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$('#container').on('click', function (event) {
  if (event.target != this) {
    alert('You clicked a descendent of #container.');
  } else {
    alert('You actually clicked #container itself.');
  }
});
```

This checks to see if the element that initiated the click event is the same exact one it's attached to.

Comment: probably add e.stopPropagation()

Answer (score 2):

This is just an extension to Bill Chriswell's answer, where children of the container's are listened for click event. To stop the animation you probably need to use [.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) method.

```js
$('#container').children().on('click', function (e) {
  
     //apply jQuery's stop() method here 
     alert("children");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    container
    <span>span 1</span><span> span 2</span>
</div>
```